# Price if condition is met

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I try to give out the real price when a condition is met. I tried using ta.valuewhen for this. Since I have to provide a source in the code, the price is always displayed after the source. So if I specify close as the source, the price is also displayed that way. Same with open. How can I display the price that is determined directly when the condition is met?
It is important that the script works in real-time mode and that I want to determine the price when the candle is set up and the conditions are met

This is what I tried:

```
 preis_short := ta.valuewhen(show_short == true, open, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't have the intrabar price actions on the historical bars. So, you won't be able to determine what the price was when something happened.

In real-time bars, `close` refers to the last (current) price. So, you can save/use that information.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Unfortunately, when I specify the source close, the close price of the candle is always given. Since the triggering of the condition can be seen in time, the condition occurs before the candle closes. Therefore, it appears that the Soure specification determines at what status the candle is evaluated and not at the price of the condition